# apache2/modules directory missing

Tags: 14.04, drivers, apache2

Somehow my /usr/lib/apache2/modules/ folder is missing is there a package or something I can get the modules from? I've tried purging and reinstalling apache and it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: How did you initially install apache?  I assume apt-get since you mention purge, but is it possible that module folder is located somewhere else?  I can't imagine how it would have disappeared and not reinstalled when you removed it and reinstalled.

Comment: Yes, apt-get, I think I actually inadvertently deleted the folder when trying to completely remove apache and wordpress, thinking that all apache related files would be installed with apt-get, but maybe this folder is not installed via apt-get? Just included in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin` - int will install a bunch of modules and recreate the directory.